# Can Tags in Gtk::TextBuffer be styled with CSS

Tags: c++, css, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm3

Using GTK-3 through Gtkmm 3.22, I am about to build a custom widget, which uses a Gtk::TextView to display various entries or messages. According to the [GTKmm-Tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-textview-buffer.html.en#textview-formatting-tags), Gtk::TextBuffer::Tag shall be used to style parts of the text differently. However, on the API doc, I find only a huge number of functions to set style properties directly, which does not seem adequate. I want just to add some CSS rule (the application has a custom CSS stylesheet) to give those specific parts of the text an uniform look, like linking them to some CSS class or similar.

What is the proper way to achieve this? Did I overlook something obvious?

PS: I am aware of the section in the Tutorial dealing with [custom style properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-custom-widgets.html.en#custom-style-properties), and also the [CSS overview in the GTK manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html) -- and thus, as a fallback, it would probably be possible to define some custom property and then pick up values programmatically and apply them to the tags to mark up the text. Just this does not feel like the right approach, because it performs local adjustments explicitly instead of linking to a rule. What am I missing here?

Comment: Unfortunately, GtkTextTag is not integrated with the CSS style mechanism.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. So is there any other known workaround to apply a style to some range of text, without littering explicit style setting code all over the code base?

Comment: It may be the case that your styled regions can be defined with regular expressions, like in the case of syntax highlighting. If that fits your use case, you could use the GtkSourceView library and do the styling with language definitions and color scheme definitions in XML.

Comment: confirmed: when using the GTK+ inspector, i.e. run with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive <MyApp>`, my tags show up in the object hierarchy, but they do not appear as CSS-Nodes. OK, so I have to think about a viable workaround

Comment: any solution in 2021?